# Is there an override for changing text size in real-time using WKWebView loading local HTML files?

Tags: html, ios, css, xcode, wkwebview

I'm currently using WKWebView to load some local HTML files for viewing in my iOS app.

I have used something like

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
```

in the source HTML file to make the whole content appear bigger - but I'd be very interested in having 'Increase text size' and 'Decrease text size' buttons to help people who need larger text to read.

Currently WKWebView allows you to pinch-zoom on the content that has been loaded, but it is not as easy to read large blocks of text like this as you have to keep panning around.